# is there a command in centos to dynamically add entries to the inittab file?

Tags: centos5

is there a command in centos to dynamically add entries to the inittab file ? I am writing a new daemon and would like the init to restart it when it dies for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the entry with echo, or whatever, then use initctl as necessary?

Comment: but when the software is uninstalled then how do you remove the entry from the file ?

Comment: sed -i -e '/something-that-identifies-the-line/d' /etc/inittab